# How do you allow another device to access your development mode server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I have a MERN web app in development mode. I want to allow my other computer and phone to test it. I am currently running the frontend on port 3000 and the backend on port 5000. I can access the site URL with another device but unless its my computer with the code I cannot log in.

How do you allow other devices to access your server and make API requests? Is there a way to still have this functionality without putting the server online?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: So you can reach the `3000` frontend from your other devices? But something is broken? You will need to share at least the console errors that you are getting in order to help. One thing that is often a lot easier to do is to use a introspective tunnel like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) or [localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/). But it is hard to say whether your issue is connectivity or code at this point.

Comment: On the secondary computer I receive a console error `POST **url-here** net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. I thought the problem was more complicated and had to do with CORS, but your answer made me realize it might be a simpler solution. I checked my BASE_URL and realized I had it on localhost. I also realized that I did not have the additional device's IP address in my allowedOrigins variable. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be to deploy the same code into two separate projects. You will have a "staging" link and a "production" link.
Deploy to both of them together or individually - Github actions can be helpful to build right away, also you can use npm scripts to trigger builds